# Why does ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance cause UserControls to not work at design-time?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, design-time, service-locator

I'm having an issue where if I call `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(type)` anywhere in my project, it causes UserControls throughout my project to stop instantiating within other controls at design-time in Visual Studio. These controls work fine at run-time however.

It is reproducible by creating a simple WpfApplication with the following 3 classes. **The first build will succeed**, and the designer will show fine. If you *rebuild*, however, it throws the error and the designer stops instantiating the UserControls within other controls. Because of this behavior, it seems like a Visual Studio bug, but I'm not sure.

When uncommented, the `#GetInstance(Type type)` function of ServiceLocator causes an Error in the error list `Cannot locate resource 'controls/test.xaml` and the designer shows an error `Cannot create an instance of "Test"` where the Test UserControl should be. When commented, there are no errors.

Test xaml class.

```
<UserControl x:Class="XamlTest.Controls.Test"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyView xaml class. (uses Test)

```
<UserControl x:Class="XamlTest.Views.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:XamlTest.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <mycontrols:Test/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A class unrelated to the UserControls that uses `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(type);`.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace XamlTest.SomeClasses
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeFunction()
        {
            // Causes Test xaml class to not instantiate at design time within MyView.
            // Does not matter what parameters you give the function.
            // Notice this class isn't even associated with any other class,
            //  and is never called, but it still causes problems.
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That is a seriously tricky question...my first thought is simply, knowing how fragile the WPF designer is in general, any kind of exception thrown at design time, even if it's caught, could cause it to fall over. At least in VS 2013...you don't specify the version. It might help in an oblique way to know that the Service Locator pattern is now widely considered a deprecated anti-pattern and you'd probably be better off with constructor injection. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: I understand about the exception and how fragile the designer can be. The silly thing is it works the first time the code is compiled from a completely clean slate. Just not on recompilation.

Using latest VS 2013, and tried on VS 2015 Preview. Same result.

In my real application, I use the UnityContainer as a provider for ServiceLocator. In general I'm just using Constructor injection, however there was this one case where I needed to instantiate based on a dynamic type variable. I guess I'll have to look for an alternative way of instantiating that.

Comment: As a workaround in my real project, I was able to expose the UnityContainer as a public property on one of my classes and use it directly.

Comment: Not sure I understand instantiation based on a dynamic type variable...a generic class of <dynamic>?, but anyway exposing the UnityContainer as a public property sounds very similar to a ServiceLocator in principle. I do wonder if this means you could have passed the Container itself via constructor, or, worst case, property or parameter injection. Highly recommend Seemann's book by the way. Cheers.

Comment: Good points. Yeah, I should have chosen my words more wisely. Just needed a type from a variable that is not known at compile time. Thanks for the resources.